# How to get the values and keys from a json deserialized/parsed string in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I have an cookie string from an array put together by C# that looks like this:

Questionnaire A:

```
[{"8872":"Yes", "9900":"Bob", "2222":"Sagat"}]
```

where the numbers are the number is the question id from my db (key) and the value is the customers response. Some time the questionnaire doesn't have the same question ids in it, so i cannot make a model to read the IDs.

example:
Questionnaire B:

```
[{"2222":"No","6756":"Brown","5416":"Jerry","4684":"Tom"}]
```

All i want to do is pull the users response to question to question 9900.

This is the work i have done so far and where its crashing:

**C#**

```
var arrString = ""[{\"8872\" : \"Yes\",\"9900\" : \"Bob\",\"2222\" : \"Sagat\"}]"


var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(arrString);

foreach (var attendee in (IEnumerable) attendeeArray)
{
  var theResponseOfQuestion9900 = attendee.9900
}
```

attendee.9900 give me an error at the '.' with *unexpected token*.

i think its because its reading the 9900 as a double instead of a key.

Comment: `var arrString = "[{"8872":"Yes", "9900":"Bob", "2222":"Sagat"}]` doesn't compile - you need to escape quotes inside a string.

Comment: @Blorgbeard  - i updated the arrString. but the issue still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deserialize to `List<Dictionary<int, string>>`

```
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<int, string>>>(json);
```

Now, you have a list of dictionaries....

Comment: thanks! that totally worked!! How would i get list dictionaries if i have an array inside my array? like if my string looked like this: [{"633" : [{"8768" : "hello","8769" : "world"}],"634" : [{"8782" : "on","8783" : "No"}]}]? Would i have to use Dictionary<int, Array>?

Comment: @NeoSketo  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<int, List<Dictionary<int,string>>>>>(json);` But it is getting too complex to process

Answer (score 1):

.NET fields and properties can't start with a digit. You can try `attendee["9900"]` to get the value you want.