# How to deserialize JSON

Tags: c#, arrays, json, string

I have a JSON string like this:

```
[{"633" : [{"8768" : "hello","8769" : "world"}],"634" : [{"8782" : "on","8783" : "No"}]}]
```

I am trying to deserialize/parse this string.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
var arrString = "[{\"633\" : [{\"8768\" : \"hello\",\"8769\" : \"world\"}],\"634\" : [{\"8782\" : \"on\",\"8783\" : \"No\"}]}]"

var attendeeArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<int, string>>>(arrString); //error
```

This gives me the error: *Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path '[0].633', line 1, position 11.*

I'm wondering if it's because I'm using `int, string`, When it should be something like `int, array (int, string)`?

**MORE INFO**

This is in regards to my earlier answered question:
[How to get the values and keys from a json deserialized/parsed string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729467/how-to-get-the-values-and-keys-from-a-json-deserialized-parsed-string-in-c)

But now i need arrays inside of arrays.

Comment: Why/how do you expect that JSON to be deserializable into a `List<Dictionary<int, string>>`?

Comment: In your previous question, you had an array of (int,string) pairs. What do you have now?

Comment: @Pillar - As you can see in the question i have an int, Array[ int, string]. but I've never had to deserialize an array inside of an array before so hence my question posted.

Comment: If a `Array[int,string]` deserializes into a `List<Dictionary<int, string>>`, then an `Array[int,Array[int,string]]` deserializes into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the key/value objects are actually wrapped in arrays. This can be deserialized to the type `List<Dictionary<int, List<Dictionary<int, string>>>>` as demonstrated below:

```
var arrString = "[{\"633\" : [{\"8768\" : \"hello\",\"8769\" : \"world\"}],\"634\" : [{\"8782\" : \"on\",\"8783\" : \"No\"}]}]";
var attendeeArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<int, List<Dictionary<int, string>>>>>(arrString);
```

The structure is essentially:

```
List
-- Dictionary<int, List>
   -- List
      -- Dictionary<int, string>
```

Comment: thanks! im trying to figure out how i can pull the top tier Key out of the array. I'm putting it in a for loop and trying attendeeArray[x].Key but its not working??

Comment: @NeoSketo: It's actually down another level because of the array. Remember you have a `List` of `Dictionary` types, so you actually access the keys with something like `attendeeArray[i][j].Key`. If you'd like, you may post another question with your current progress and I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth reconsidering your JSON schema, but if you want to go that route, here is how you could loop through the JSON:

```
dynamic numList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
    @"[{
        ""633"": [{
            ""8768"": ""hello"",
            ""8769"": ""world""
        }],
        ""634"": [{
            ""8782"": ""on"",
            ""8783"": ""No""
        }]
    }]"
    );

foreach (dynamic recordList in numList)
    foreach (dynamic record in recordList)
    {
        //recordKey would be "633" for:
        //"633": [{
        //    "8768": "hello"
        //}]
        var recordKey = record.Name;

        //.First.First because of the awkward JSON structure.
        foreach (dynamic entry in record.First.First)
        {
            //for {"8768": "hello"}
            //key would be "8768", value would be "hello"
            var key = entry.Name;
            var value = entry.Value;
        }
    }
```

You could then take the recordKey and the entry key/value and do with them what you will (including stuffing them into whatever formatted data structure you prefer).

Better than trying to work with the typed deserialized value:

```
List<Dictionary<int, List<Dictionary<int, string>>>>
```

...anyway.

Comment: Most excellent, clean example! Especially just using strings instead of int. Thank you thank you!

Comment: do you know of anyway i can pull the value of 633's 8769's value from the record in recordList loop?

Comment: The innermost foreach loop should get you that value on its second iteration. Otherwise, if you at least know you'll only have two number in each entry, you might be able to just look at the indexed entries of record.First[1] or something.